# Assigning variable Row numbers to fixed Columns in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code module that adds rows to a sheet and then populates them with formulas. Below the last row is a Totals row i.e. a non-contiguous range H21:M21,W21:AC21,AF21,AL21:AR21,AU21.

What I want to achieve is assign the row number from a variable that has been used to find the last row (before the totals row) i.e. i1stSumRow and then copy the Sum formula to each cell in the range.The column ID is fixed, only the row number changes.

The section of code is as follows:

```
    With ActiveSheet
    i1stSumRow = Cells(.Rows.count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("G" & (i1stSumRow)).Select
    End With

ActiveCell.Select
formulatext = "=SUM(G" & (intLast_CS_Sheet) & ":" & "G" & (i1stSumRow - 2) & ")"
ActiveCell.Formula = formulatext
Selection.Copy
Range("H21:M21,W21:AC21,AF21,AL21:AR21,AU21").Select
Range("AU21").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("C10").Select
```

I tried Range("H" & (i1stSumRow) & ":" & "M" & (i1stSumRow) etc. but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
for j = 7 to 13  //Columns G through M
  cells(i1stSumRow, j) = worksheetfunction.sum(range(cells(intLast_CS_Sheet,j),cells(i1stSumRow - 2, j)))
next j
```

Comment: Then you could copy that code for the other ranges.

Comment: Thanks @Matt. Although the variables have the correct values, the loop does not create the Sum formula in the first cell or move to the next cell.

Comment: RC reference might be best for this, then. In the loop have instead `cells(i1stSumRow, j) = "=SUM(R" & intLast_CS_Sheet & "C:R" & i1stSumRow - 2 & "C)"`

Comment: Thanks @Matt. I was almost there but the syntax beat me! With the addition of:    Cells(i1stSumRow, j).Select    it all works!